# Resharper "No Suggestions" box

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I noticed that Resharper adds "No Suggestion" box on new properties in C# classes. Like this:

[image: No Suggestion box is annoyance]

This "No Suggestion" box does not add anything to the code, only obstructs lines of code below - and that is an annoyance.

Any way to make Resharper not show this box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the `prop` Live Template and remove the macro associated with the `$NAME$` variable of the property.

What ReSharper is trying to do is suggest a name for the property, based on the type. If it's a `bool` property, there's not much it can suggest, but if it's a complex type, such as `Address`, then it can suggest a name such as `Address`. Also, if it's a `List<Address>`, ReSharper will suggest `Addresses` or `List`. So, it can be useful.

However, it isn't terribly helpful to show `No suggestions` - it might be nicer to just not show anything if the list is empty. I've added a feature request you can vote on and track: [RSRP-453668](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-453668)

Comment: Ah, voice of reason. I suspected this is not optional and I have to live with this. I notice there is another identical feature request linked, so it is not only me. Thanks, Matt